# Outlook 2013 / Office 365 Single Inbox for multiple accounts

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have move a client away from an old self hosted POP3 mail solution to office 365 and I need to try to configure his outlook so that emails come through in the way he is used to.

He has 4 different email accounts across 3 domains:

- name@website1.com
- othername@website1.com
- name@website2.com
- name@website3.com

With pop emails from all 4 accounts would be stored in a single inbox in a combined PST file. He could reply to an email recieved by any account as that account with the relevant signature automatically upon clicking reply.

With the new office 365 setup I can only see two possible options. Having individual inboxes in the sidebar for each account, which he does not want. Or the way that I currently have things set up, use rules within Exchange admin to automatically redirect all mail to a single inbox (name@website1.com), he can then manually change the from address and signature each time he replies. Which is unecessary extra steps.

Is there anyway to have a single inbox for multiple imap accounts within Outlook 2013, where the reply account can be automatically detected?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to my tests, with features in Outlook alone, we could only manually send on behalf as those reply account and could not make the reply account be automatically detected.